# RxJs stack observables

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to lower my line count in a application, but I can't get my observables to work ...

So I have the following scenario:

```
let openDialog = function (): Observable<any> {
    // some logic that defines x
    let x = 0;

    // return
    return Observable.create(observable => {

        this.handleDialogResult(x).subscribe(
            () => {
                observable.next();
                observable.complete();
            },
            e => {
                observable.error(e);
                observable.complete();
            }
        )
    });
}


let handleDialogResult = function (x): Observable<any> {
    switch (x) {
        case 1:
            return this.doMagic('Magic1');
        case 2:
            return this.doMagic('Magic2');
    }
}


let doMagic = function (x): Observable<any> {
   // some magic
}
```

then I would think I get the same functionality when you do the following:

```
let openDialog = function (): Observable<any> {
    // some logic that defines x
    let x = 0;

    // return
    return Observable.create(observable => {
        this.handleDialogResult.flatMap(observable)
    });
}


let handleDialogResult = function (x): Observable<any> {
    switch (x) {
        case 1:
            return this.doMagic('Magic1');
        case 2:
            return this.doMagic('Magic2');
    }
}


let doMagic = function (x): Observable<any> {
   // some magic
}
```

but this isn't the case, it the Observable openDialog, never get's finished/completed. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need to `flatMap` the stream. It doesn't look like a stream of stream

Answer (score 1):

Hum, this line looks suspicious:

```
return Observable.create(observable => {
    this.handleDialogResult.flatMap(observable)
});
```

Why would you want to create a new observable while you already have one: the one returned by `handleDialogResult`?

I am not sure I fully understand what your code should do, but for your stream to end when the first value is emitted (it is what your initial code seems to be doing), you need to only `take` one value

Your code would look like this

```
return this.handleDialogResult(x).take(1)
```

If the stream is a stream containing another stream (as your `flatMap` suggests), then you would also need to flatten the stream using the `switch` operator

```
return this.handleDialogResult(x).switch().take(1)
```